# Sharing cache between Apollo GraphQL queries

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am beginning with Apollo, and attempting to cache the results of one query for use by another component. In the real application this data is tabular, I want to fetch all the data in a single query for performance reasons. The cells in the table have complex logic associated with them, so for testing purposes I want them to just take a type ID, and appear to fetch the live value for that ID, creating an easier boundary for mocking.

I have made a minimal GQL schema to demonstrate this:

```
type DataType {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  liveValue: Float!
}

type Channel {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  dataTypes: [DataType!]!
}

type Query {
  channels: [Channel!]!
  dataType(id: ID!): DataType
}
```

I have two queries running against this schema:

Query 1:

```js
const TABLE_QUERY = gql`
    query TableQuery {
        channels {
            id
            name
            dataTypes {
                id
                name
                liveValue
            }
        }
    }
`
```

Query 2:

```js
const CELL_QUERY = gql`
    query CellQuery($typeID: ID!) {
        dataType(id: $typeID) {
            id
            liveValue
        }
    }
`;
```

And a very simple react component consisting of some rows, one row per endpoint, trying to fetch its live value individually:

```
function App() {
    const {data} = useQuery<TableResponse>(TABLE_QUERY, {
        pollInterval: 5000,
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {
                data?.channels?.flatMap(channel => channel.dataTypes.map(type => (
                    <Row key={type.id} id={type.id} />
                )))
            }
        </div>
    );
}

const Row = (props: {id: string}) => {
    const { data} = useQuery<CellResponse>(CELL_QUERY, {
        pollInterval: 5000,
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-only',
        variables: {typeID: props.id}
    });

    return <h6>{`${props.id}: ${data?.dataType.liveValue ?? '-'}`}</h6>;
}
```

I can see in the Apollo DevTools that I am getting properly normalised cache entries for DataType with the expected keys, e.g `DataType:{"id":"C1/SPEED"}`  and the root query looks like it is referencing the correct cache object `__ref:"DataType:{"id":"C1/SPEED"}"`

But in practice when I run this code I get a separate network request for each row, which defeats the point.

There is a full minimal express apollo server below for testing this:

```json
{
  "name": "test-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.10.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.13.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

```js
import {ApolloServer} from '@apollo/server';
import {startStandaloneServer} from '@apollo/server/standalone'

const typeDefs = `
    type DataType {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        liveValue: Float!
    }

    type Channel {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        dataTypes: [DataType!]!
    }

    type Query {
        channels: [Channel!]!
        dataType(id: ID!): DataType
    }
`;

function createDataType(channelId, name) {
    return {
        id: `${channelId}/${name}`,
        name,
        liveValue: Math.random() * 100 
    };
}

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        channels: () => [
            {id: 'C1', name: 'Channel 1'},
            {id: 'C2', name: 'Channel 2'},
        ],
        dataType: (_, { id }) => {
            const [channelId, dataTypeName] = id.split('/');
            return createDataType(channelId, dataTypeName, dataTypeName);
        },
    },
    Channel: {
        dataTypes: (channel) => [
            createDataType(channel.id, 'Speed'),
            createDataType(channel.id, 'Voltage'),
        ],
    },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen: { port: 8123 },
});

console.log(`  Server ready at: ${url}`);
```

I have tried using cache redirects to explicitly link my request to the ID as described here:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#cache-redirect

If I add console logging to the read endpoint I can see it is being hit, and has the correct ID, but it still decides to send a network request (even though the only fields it is requesting (liveValue and id) can be seen in the cache in apollo dev tools)

```js
 new InMemoryCache({
        typePolicies: {
            Query: {
                fields: {
                    dataType: {
                        read(_, {args, toReference}) {
                            return toReference({__typename: 'DataType', id: args?.id});
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            DataType: {
                keyFields: ["id"]
            }
        }
    })
```